# In a pandas Dataframe how to change the acronym for month to number month?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I know this question has been asked but, there is a twist to mine I don't have english acronyms but spanish acronyms

so my `df['Month']` would be something like (abr for apr), (Ene for Jan), (Dic for Dec) and (Ago for Aug). Those are the changes in acronym so I cannot use a the Calendar library and I have tried doing it with a dictionary but for some reason it says that it being in a pandas Series is not a recognisible type.

An example of the Data frame would be

```
    A
   Abr
   Ene
   Jun
   Jul
   Nov
   Dic
```

The out come I would like would be

```
    A
    04
    01
    06
    07
    11
    12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do, for example

```
# in English, change to your wish
month_names = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar',...]

month_dict = {v:f'{k:02d}' for k,v in enumerate(month_names, start=1)}
df['A'] = df['A'].map(month_dict)
```

Comment: Quang Hoang When I do this it returns Nan instead of the numeric values  month_names = ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic']

month_dict = {v:f'{k:02d}' for k,v in enumerate(month_names, start=1)}
data['Mes'] = data['Mes'].map(month_dict) am i doing something wrong

Comment: Check if your `Mes` column has leading/trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

expanding on Quang's answer, if you know the months, creating a dict with the numbers is simple :

```
    months_dict = {'ene': 1,
 'feb': 2,
 'mar': 3,
 'abr': 4,
 'may': 5,
 'jun': 6,
 'jul': 7,
 'ago': 8,
 'sep': 9,
 'oct': 10,
 'nov': 11,
 'dic': 12}
```

#### Use `map`, and `str.zfill`

```
# strip white space, lower case column and map to dict, using zfill to 0 pad your number.
df['B'] = df['A'].str.strip().str.lower().map(month_dict).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print(df)
       A   B
0     Abr  04
1     Ene  01
2     Jun  06
3     Jul  07
4     Nov  11
5     Dic  12
```